# Codelite not compiling and running program

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codelite

I'm new to coding and i am trying to learn C, I installed Codelite and tried to compile the default hello world thing but I just returns this, is something going on or am I just stupid?

the default thing is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\\n");
```

Codelite is returning this when I click "Build":

```
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1. Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Matheus/OneDrive/Documentos/Testing/Testing2'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make[1]: *** [Testing2.mk:86: MakeIntermediateDirs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Matheus/OneDrive/Documentos/Testing/Testing2'
make: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
=== build completed successfully (0 errors, 0 warnings) ===
```

And when I click "Run" this shows up:

```
==== Program exited with exit code: 0 ====
Time elapsed: 000:00.000 (MM:SS.MS)
Press any key to continue...
```

I don't know anything about coding i only tried to change to build settings and returning it to the normal state but i didn't work either

Comment: Your code is incomplete to start with.

Comment: Is that so? What should i do? I'm following a course but the instructor did not show what to do in that case.

Comment: Is this all the code you have? Or is there more below it? Remember, in C, once you open a bracket, remember to close it at some point! ^^